# loading images returns Assertion Failed in function cv::inRange

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

1. Having issues getting code to read image folder path. Looks as though it is creating a non-existent path. I have three .py files running to run the main one img2bim.py. Below are the contents at thee error line (not the entire code file):

img2bim.py

```
    14# model = {
    15#    "beam": beam.find_steel_beams(image),
```

beam.py

```
    63# def find_steel_beams(img, debug=False):
    64#    image = wall.remove_walls(img)
```

wall.py

```
    7# def remove_walls(img):
    8#     rimg = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
    9#     kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    10#    lower = np.array([190, 190, 190])
    11#    upper = np.array([195, 195, 195])
    12#    initial_mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
```

2. The traceback of cmd.exe command line is below:

```
    > python VIF\img2bim.py

    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "VIF\img2bim.py", line 15, in <module>
          "beam": beam.find_steel_beams(image),
       File "C:\Python\Python37-32\VIF\beam.py", line 64, in find_steel_beams
          image = wall.remove_walls(img)
       File "C:\Python\Python37-32\VIF\wall.py", line 12, in remove_walls
          initial_mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1766: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ! _src.empty() in function 'cv::inRange'
```

Comment: what's the shape of the image `img`? Can you run `print(img.shape)` and tell us what the output is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV error messages are unclear... 
This error message:

```
 (-215:Assertion failed) ! _src.empty() in function 'cv::inRange'
```

Says that the source argument in the inRange function (in your case, img) is empty.
This probably occurred because you misspelled the image's file name when you read it.

Comment: Found it was not a misspelling, but I was calling a folder of images instead of one specific instance. After I added to the file path, the script ran fine! Thanks for the answer, it lead me down the right path to fixing the issue and helped me read the error messages a better.